# Firebase / AngularFire - Grabbing a range of children

Tags: firebase, angularfire

How can I grab a range of children (such as the second child, through the fifth.) using a query in Firebase? I've tried stuff like:

```
new Firebase(config.fb + '/content/posts').startAt(null, 1).endAt(null, 5)
and
new Firebase(config.fb + '/content/posts').startAt(1).endAt(5)
```

Here's the two example 'posts':

```js
{
    -KDa3Ml3gMcljX6ojEs3: {
        title: 'Example post 3',
        body: 'This is a test'
    }, 
    -KDa3NLvBpLzXMC0npI_: {
        title: 'Example post 3',
        body: 'This is a test' 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do `1` and `5` refer to here? Are they keys, priorities or the value of a specific property?

Comment: I'm just trying to grab a range of posts starting with the first key that shows up (1) to the last key (5). The 'posts' where pushed so it's ordered by a unique id. If that makes sense.

Comment: I tried answering, but it's quite underspecified at the moment. Add a snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshot) and add the exact code that you've tried against that snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var posts = new Firebase(config.fb + '/content/posts').orderByKey().startAt(1).endAt(5);
$scope.posts = $firebaseArray(posts);
```

Alternatively, you can print them with something like:

```
var posts = new Firebase(config.fb + '/content/posts').orderByKey().startAt(1).endAt(5);
posts.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.val());
  });
});
```

Update (based on the additional information you provided):

Firebase can query on:

- the key of the items
- the value of the items
- the value of a child property of the items

It *cannot* query on the index of the items as you seem to be trying to do. The only way to do that would be to:

- use that index as the key of the items
- add the index as the value of a child property of the items

If you try to do either of those, you'll run into the reason why Firebase doesn't support this: it is incredibly difficult to scale such index-based operations for a massively multi-user application. For a broader explanation of the topic, see [arrays in Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase).

Comment: I'm getting angular.js:13294 Error: Query: When ordering by key, the argument passed to startAt(), endAt(),or equalTo() must be a string.

Comment: Note, the keys are 'pushed'

Comment: I added a screenshot of the data

Comment: Just saw it.. I added a text version too